# Qual a Diferença entre $this->loadView() e $this->load->view() no codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou refatorando um código, vi que o programador anterior fez a escrita de $this->loadView(), eu sempre usei o $this->load->view() desde quando aprendi Codeigniter.
E verifiquei que o comportamento é o mesmo, ambos carregam a view, no entanto um comportamento em um dos arquivos apresentou comportamento diferente. Por isso levantei essa dúvida, se há diferenças entre essas duas escritas.

Comment: certeza que esse $this->loadView() é realmente do codeigniter? não tem nada sobre ele na documentação do codeigniter...

Comment: Sim, eu também busquei na documentação e não achei, porém o código que peguei está escrito desta forma, por esse motivo achei bem estranho.  Durante a refatoração até troquei para $this->load->view(), alguns funcionaram normalmente, outros deram erro... Por isso acredito que deve tar alguma diferença entre eles.

Comment: Mas não necessariamente quer dizer que seja do codeigniter, pode ser um método que foi criado por alguém, assim como vc disse o programador anterior usava então pode ser q até ele mesmo que tenha criado.